# introduction to algorithms exercise 8.3-2 understanding stability

Tags: algorithm, sorting, design-patterns

**when I got the answer:
http://clrs.skanev.com/08/03/02.html for exercise 8.3-2, 
I could not understand how to use index specifically to solve it. 
Could someone please show it step by step or interpret why is Θ(n)?**

and here is the question and answer:

Which of the following sorting algorithms are stable: insertion sort, merge sort, heapsort, and quicksort? Give a simple scheme that makes any sorting algorithm stable. How much additional time and space does your scheme entail?

Stable: Insertion sort, merge sort

Not stable: Heapsort, quicksort

We can make any algorithm stable by mapping the array to an array of pairs, where the first element in each pair is the original element and the second is its index. Then we sort lexicographically. This scheme takes additional Θ(n) space.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of sorting, "stable" means that when a collection containing some elements with equivalent value is sorted, those elements stay in the same order with respect to each other.

So a sorting algorithm can be made stable by storing the original index of each element, and using that index as a secondary way of sorting elements with equal primary value.

To implement this the comparison function (for example <) would be implemented
so A < B returns true if A.PrimarySortValue < B.PrimarySortValue, and returns (A.OrginalIndex < B.OriginalIndex) when A.PrimarySortValue == B.PrimarySortValue. otherwise (when A.PrimarySortValue > B.PrimarySortValue) it returns false;

This requires one additional OriginalIndex value to be stored per element. There are n elements hence Θ(n) extra space is required.